# Selenium sendKeys() different behaviour for Chrome, Firefox and Safari

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2, java

Below is simple snippet of code:

```
@FindBy(className = "element-to-press")
private WebElement elementToPress;

// some other code

Keys move = Keys.ARROW_DOWN;
gridContainer.sendKeys(move);
```

In **Firefox** everything works fine.

In **Chrome** I've got `"org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element"` error

**Safari** does not react for `sendKeys()`

Also I've tried to use another approach:

```
Keys move = Keys.ARROW_DOWN;
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).click(); // to focus on element
actions.sendKeys(move).perform();
```

This code fixed **Chrome's** `"cannot focus element"` error, but browser still does not react for `Keys.ARROW_DOWN/Keys.ARROW_UP/Keys.ARROW_LEFT/Keys.ARROW_RIGHT` events

Safari and Firefox do not react for `sendKeys()` as well.

I cannot understand what is going on and how I can make my code run for all this browsers.

**Environment**:

- OS X 10.9.5
- Latest version of Chrome/Safari/Firefox
- Selenium version 2.44.0

**UPD**

[Madhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3122133/madhan) has found an universal solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547459/selenium-sendkeys-different-behaviour-for-chrome-firefox-and-safari/31559637#31559637)

Comment: You have mentioned at first that everything works well for Firefox and then again mentioned it doesn't works for Firefox? Also can you give the AUT URL or HTML snippet?

Comment: Closing because duplicate on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547459/selenium-sendkeys-different-behaviour-for-chrome-firefox-and-safari/31559637#31559637